# Output of the program((confused))

Tags: post-increment, pre-increment

Can you explain the output of the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{  
    int a=10;

    int x=(a++)+(++a)+(a++)+(a++)+(++a);

    cout<<x<<endl;
    x+= (++a);

    cout<<x<<" "<<a<<endl;
}
```

the output is:

```
62

78 16
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Answer (score 0):

A good example of why pre- and post-increment is not always a good idea. Applying the pre-and post-incrments in seqence to the initial vale of `a` (10) you get

This line:

```
int x=(a++)+(++a)+(a++)+(a++)+(++a);
```

becomes:

```
x = 10 + 12 + 12 + 13 + 15 // 62
```

While `x+= (++a);` becomes

```
x += 16;  // x=78
```

Answer (score 0):

a++ increases the value of a after using the value of a whereas ++a increases the value before using its value.
so in `int x = x=(a++)+(++a)+(a++)+(a++)+(++a);` the first a++ will use the value 10 and increase value of a to 11, now the next one, ++a, will increase the value of a from 11 to value 12 and then use it.
so it becomes:

```
x = 10 + 12 + 12 + 13 + 15 = 62
```

and the value of x at this point is 15. next output can be explained similarly. Cheers!